# Install grails as another user with sudo

Tags: grails, sudo, gvm

I want to install grails in my vagrant provision bootstrap bash file (which is executed as root). I tried to change the installation like shown on the [grails manual](https://grails.org/download.html):

```
curl -s get.gvmtool.net | sudo -u vagrant -H bash
sudo -u vagrant -H bash "$HOME/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"
sudo -u vagrant -H bash gvm install grails
```

But this gives errors:

```
bash: /root/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh: Permission denied
bash: gvm: No such file or directory
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what errors might that be?

Comment: first of all you are not supposed to run the init script, but you have to source it.  second problem is, that `gvm` is a shell function and no script.  i'd make sure, that the sourcing happens in the .profile of your vagrant user and then "bash -c 'gvm install grails' could work via sudo. to try things out i'd start with `sudo -u vagrant -H bash -i` and try to make it first work within the user.

Comment: `-i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.` why shoul that help? the vagrant provision script is not interactive at all ;)

Comment: doing so with a local account for testing would help to understand, how gvm works (it sources gvm-init and provides a function gvm). it would have to be at least something in one line: `'bash -c "source ...gvm-init.sh; gvm install grails"'`

Comment: `The -i (simulate initial login) option ... This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```
curl -s get.sdkman.io | sudo -u vagrant -H bash -i
sudo -u vagrant -H bash -i 'source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"; sdk install grails'
```

> The -i (simulate initial login) option
>   ... This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for
>   execution.